# Importing libraries gives error in Play Framework

Tags: java, json, playframework-2.3

I am currently trying to import simple objects such as JSON in Play Framework but I keep getting errors. Does anybody know how to avoid this?
Here is my code:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;

import views.html.*;

public class Application extends Controller {

public static Result index() {
    return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
}

// Step where the information is READ
public static JSONObject get(){
    JSONObject obj = null; //get json object from localhost:9000
    return obj;
}
}
```

The errors I get are:

```
 C:\Users\eedcoro\activator-1.2.2-minimal\manager\app\controllers\Application.java:5package
 org.json does not exist
 import org.json.JSONArray;
 ^
 C:\Users\eedcoro\activator-1.2.2-minimal\manager\app\controllers\Application.java:6package
 org.json does not exist
 import org.json.JSONException;
 ^
 C:\Users\eedcoro\activator-1.2.2-minimal\manager\app\controllers\Application.java:7package org.json does not exist
 import org.json.JSONObject;
 ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those classes aren't included with Play (at least the version I'm using). If you want to use the org.json.* files then you can download them from [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java) but, otherwise, I'd recommend using the Jackson library which comes bundled with Play:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaJsonActions

Comment: Ok so then how would you add these files in your path?

Comment: Put the Jar files in your project's "lib" directory and they should get picked up the next time you run the app (if not, try a "play clean" first). If you're using Eclipse or IntelliJ then you'll need to add those Jars to your project's classpath, otherwise it'll say there's an error.